# In TypeScript, why does an inferred type for a union type take both paths of a ternary operator?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Inferring a type inside a type definition appears to follow both paths in a ternary when the inferred Type is enumerable (vs uncountable).

In the code below, when the inferred type can be enumerated (is a union of multiple values), the type definition appears to take two paths and return a union of the true and false paths of the second (interior) ternary operation. However, when the inferred type is uncountable (numeric, string - so infinite), only one of the interior ternary paths is taken.

Note that in the `alt` case when there is no `infer` the type is narrowed as expected.

What's going on here? Why does TypeScript behave this way in the presence of `infer`?

I'm not saying this is incorrect behavior, I'm just not even sure where this is documented or how to find it in the docs.

Thanks.

```
// type of union1 == 0 | 1; type of alt1 == 0
var union1:
    boolean extends infer Type ?
        Type extends true ?
            1 :
            0 :
        never;

var alt1: boolean extends true ? 1 : 0;


// type of union4 == 0; type of alt4 == 0
var union4:
    string extends infer Type ?
        Type extends "a" ?
            1 :
            0 :
        never;
var alt4: string extends "a" ? 1 : 0;
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-XSZXqb3Rfbc7P1o7p5jJaY3advGrs7wi+XGNXtEbG8XbezXeMXsIy4Q1pyEHALS9McHSMR8BywC88CtW0sAONAXltZI4GSNdvyTENtz7NMiwPPDUCwnJiMvc8bzzAtaK9O9y0nChugQpCULQjCKNwwNyOwv8OwAntJX1ECBzeSCrRYsDIBeRCEGRKYvz4zdQx3Kj9z7Q9+MohiM2zfSY3o3NMyYh8q26eSfCUn4VKbFIBO2c9hKAA)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types

Comment: @Mayfair 's link combined with the sentence right before "Literal inference" section on [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference)  (The type `boolean` itself is actually just an alias for the union `true | false`) explains this behaviour

Comment: @Mayfair & Alex Chashin, thank you for the info. I’ve seen Distributive Conditional Types before, but never truly understood them. I do now. I knew Boolean was a union (see the TS playground) and suspected that was related to the behavior, but that was as far as I got. Also, when I read how to avoid DCTs (even tho I didn’t grok them) by wrapping in [], I thought maybe that was a special language feature, not taking advantage of the type behavior related to parameterization of complex types. I appreciate the links and the info.